# Create MacOS style screenshots with dropshadow using Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

How do I add the drop shadow to any image with imagemagick to create the same effect that the screenshot on MacOS adds to screenshots when screencapture shadow is true?

I am showing before and after to clarify the effect I am seeking.

[image: Source image]

[image: Target image]

I have tried to identify the shape of the shadow in the target picture 
[image: Shadow profile in Target]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty similar, but you can play around with the parameters:

```
convert screenshot.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 50x50+30+30 \) +swap -background white -layers merge +repage result.png
```

[image]

---

Here I change the shadow colour to magenta and shift it and place it on a yellow background layer so you can see the effect:

```
convert screenshot.png \( +clone -background magenta -shadow 200x50+30+30 \) +swap -background yellow  -layers merge +repage result.png
```

[image]

Comment: I edited this response by mistake. PLEASE cancel my edit and roll back.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 with Ventura, this seems to be the closest I can get to reproducing the drop shadow:

```
convert test.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 40x50+0+36 \) +swap -background transparent -layers merge +repage test-shadow.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to work. I've done it twice -- once to show the shadow more explicitly, and then once to show the desired, finished output.

```
# adds the shadow
convert source.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 100x40+0+16 \) \
+swap -background none -layers merge +repage output.png

# adds the additional space like MacOSX
convert output.png -bordercolor none -border 32 target.png
```

[image]

#### Caveats:

1. The padding on should be 20px less on the top and 20px more on the bottom; this solution is not perfect in that regard.
2. The OSX screenshow draws a white border around the image, including the rounded corners. I could not duplicate that.
3. The shadow from osx screencapture looks more blurred but I don't know how to measure the blue and calibrate the solution to that.

#### Highlighted shadow to show shape and blurring

[image]